# Control Over Robot Babies

Tags: futurama

Robots can reproduce.  The process in which code and characteristics is split, isn't 100% from both parents, but random between the two parents.

Does that mean that the robots made from this process cannot be controlled by Mom?  Or is it up to random chance to decide if Mom still has control over them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**More than likely, Mom has encoded any robot whether produced in her factory or though the mysterious process of "[robot reproduction](http://theinfosphere.org/The_Bots_and_the_Bees)" to encode the domination of Mom's robotic control system into them.**

She has shown herself to be a cruel and shrewd woman especially where her robots are concerned. I cannot imagine she would allow any process, including "robot reproduction" to produce a product she would lose control over.

Despite the fact that Robot Lincoln freed robots from slavery, she has shown she still possess control over them when it is convenient for her to do so, as seen in the episode, [Mother's Day](http://theinfosphere.org/Mother%27s_Day).

Answer (score 1):

If it works like human genetics, then any code that both robots share will be passed down, except in the case of mutations. Since we don't get to see the details, it could be that mutation is prevented in the control regions of the robotic "codeome".